# Is there a way to avoid re download source(image, audio, image) when use innerHTML or cloneNode to clone them?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I found that when use innerHTML to clone the node.
It will automatically re download the same source again.
Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid the behaviour - when an `<img>` element is inserted into the DOM or the `src` changes, the browser gets the resource.

You can mitigate the impact though - there are several ways coming to mind:

1. Use effective caching. When the cloned image results in a `304` response the image data won't be re-transmitted but the locally cached version will be used.
2. Use a service worker to cache the image and use a "cache-first" strategy where the service worker always immediately responds with the locally cached version.
3. Do a `fetch` for the image, create a data URL and use the data URL as a source for the original and the cloned images. Note that data URLs are larger than the actual binary data, due to the encoding, though.

Here's a sample for (3):

```
const img = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(img);
fetch('https://example.com/image.jpg')
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
.then(dataUrl => {
  // load the image via the created data URI
  img.src = dataUrl;
  // clone the image
  setTimeout(() => {
    const clone = img.cloneNode();
    document.body.appendChild(clone); // won't request the image from the server again.
  }, 1000);
});
```